# Using CSS content to create a link

Tags: css, separation-of-concerns

I want to replace a text with a clickable link in CSS.

So far I get:

```
.myclass {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.myclass:before {
    content: 'My page: ' url(http://www.myawesomepage.com) 'myawesomepage';
    visibility:visible;
}
```

This is what I got:

```
My page: myawesomepage
```

This is what I want:

```
My page: <a href="http://www.myawesomepage.com">myawesomepage</a>
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: Repeat after me: HTML is for content, CSS is for styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` must be a string so:

```
.myclass:before {
    content: 'My page: <a href="http://www.myawesomepage.com">myawesomepage</a>';
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```css
    .myclass:before {
        content: 'My page: <a href="http://www.myawesomepage.com">myawesomepage</a>';
        visibility:visible;
    }
```

```html
<div class="myclass">Hello</div>
```

But this will not create a link, just text.

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question which asks how to create a link.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS. Just answering how the OP should fix their own CSS declaration to realize that.

Comment: He's not asking you to do that and it still does not answer the question. On top of that, your CSS should be up-to-date by using two colons in `::before`.

Comment: Sometimes people don't understand why *what they are doing* does not work as they thought. I don't know what I can do from here if the question does not have as satisfying answer, esp. to **you** given that the OP accepted my answer: it may have help.

Comment: His accepting your answer clearly does not line up with what he asks so I voted to close this whole thing as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add html to the content in css.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content):

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for reparsing).

This mean that code:

```css
    .myclass:before {
        content: 'My page: <a href="http://www.myawesomepage.com">myawesomepage</a>';
        visibility:visible;
    }
```

will render a following output:

```
 My page: <a href="http://www.myawesomepage.com">myawesomepage</a>
```

You can get more information on use of content from this [article](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

Comment: How do you know the OP didn't just want it as plain text?

Comment: @CharlieFish Cause the title specifically says he wants to create a link.

Comment: This answers the question and should be the accepted answer!  @SergeyRudenko Please expand on your correct answer and not just a link to the article.